# Facebook Textarea

Tags: html, css

how facebook show textarea which does not have icon for draging at the bottom-right corner

when i create textarea it shows dragiging icon at bottom left corner

but in facebook website they use textarea i checked it using html inspector.

as this images shows . i want to hide this

[image]

and in facebook

[image]

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<style type="text/css">
    #textarea {
        border: 1px #ddd solid;
        width: 400px;
        height: 120px;
        font: 9pt Consolas;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the browser not to allow resizing with `resize: none`

```
#textarea {
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    font: 9pt Consolas;
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Neither comment box nor post box are resizable

Answer (score 0):

Now just define

```
#textarea{
resize:none;
}
```

More info http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Comment: now you can used this in css this is allow to facebook resizing

Comment: can u tell me where r u apply this i mean can u show the facebook code if you have apply ......

Comment: i did not applied facebook code but i want make like facebook textarea